# Button OnClick Listener wont call Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclicklistener

I'm attempting to prompt an `AlertDialog` whenever a button is pressed however I've only been able to successfully implement (using a tutorial) a successful `AlertDialog` on the first of three buttons.

Once I added:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

none of the buttons work anymore and the application force closes I know I'm overlooking something simple or simply not coding this correctly.

(Any help is GREATLY appreciated!)

---

### JAVA:

```
package com.example.linkingmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.newdevicebtn:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, App2Activity.class));
        return true;
        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }   
     }

final Context context = this;
private Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

// add button listener
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        context);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Settings Menu");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Delete Edit or Link?")
        .setCancelable(false)
         .setNeutralButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
        //start new activity
     Intent intentApp2Activity = new Intent(AppActivity.this, User1Settings.class);
     startActivity(intentApp2Activity);

}
  })
        .setPositiveButton("Link",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
        //start new activity

        Intent intentApp2Activity = new Intent(AppActivity.this, User1.class);
        startActivity(intentApp2Activity);

        // if this button is clicked, close
        // current activity
        AppActivity.this.finish();
    }
  })    
        .setNegativeButton("Delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
}}
```

---

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/link_devices"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/textView1"    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Core Device 1" android:onClick="onPopupBtClick" />
 <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Core Device 2" android:onClick="onPopupBtClick" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Core Device 3" android:onClick="onPopupBtClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### LOGCAT:

```
03-12 21:22:28.194: E/Trace(1648): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-12 21:22:28.714: D/dalvikvm(1648): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 8% free 2467K/2676K, paused 83ms, total 86ms
03-12 21:22:28.794: I/dalvikvm-heap(1648): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.062MB for 3686416-byte allocation
03-12 21:22:28.854: D/dalvikvm(1648): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 6065K/6280K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
03-12 21:22:28.971: D/dalvikvm(1648): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6065K/6280K, paused 8ms+7ms, total 118ms
03-12 21:22:30.784: D/libEGL(1648): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-12 21:22:30.793: D/(1648): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1a5180, tid 1648
03-12 21:22:30.885: D/libEGL(1648): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-12 21:22:30.904: D/libEGL(1648): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-12 21:22:31.024: W/EGL_emulation(1648): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-12 21:22:31.055: D/OpenGLRenderer(1648): Enabling debug mode 0
03-12 21:22:32.973: D/dalvikvm(1648): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12K, 3% free 6125K/6280K, paused 84ms, total 99ms
03-12 21:22:33.063: I/dalvikvm-heap(1648): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.634MB for 3686416-byte allocation
03-12 21:22:33.333: D/dalvikvm(1648): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 2% free 9722K/9884K, paused 110ms+8ms, total    261ms
03-12 21:22:35.783: W/EGL_emulation(1648): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-12 21:25:49.243: D/AndroidRuntime(1648): Shutting down VM
03-12 21:25:49.243: W/dalvikvm(1648): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method    onPopupBtClick(View) in the activity class com.example.linkingmanager.AppActivity for onClick handler on view class   android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onPopupBtClick [class android.view.View]
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
03-12 21:25:49.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1648):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3):

By calling these one after another:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); // This obliterates the previous value of button
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3); // This obliterates the previous value of button
```

You are *overwriting* the previous variable. Either use different variables or do the work you want before overriding its value:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
//etc.

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
//etc.
```

---

As far as the error you see, you have defined an OnClickListener in your XML with:

```
android:onClick="onPopupBtClick"
```

But failed to write this method in your Activity...

```
public void onPopupBtClick(View view) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I removed android:onClick="onPopupBtClick"

and modified my java according to the method mentioned above - however it is still crashing / causing a force close : (

JAVA:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HOoxxHSXNc9on015tFR3KmPOkUOX6jRSm3ic29DLFRA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I need all 3 buttons to call the alert dialog - every time I try to do so (shown below) and using the method shown above - it fails. Can someone take a look at this updated source code? (it's too long to fit in a comment) 


https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HOoxxHSXNc9on015tFR3KmPOkUOX6jRSm3ic29DLFRA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Remove the onPopupBtClick off the xml views. It cannot find a method in your activity called onPopupBtClick and therefor is crashing

Also you cannot assign 3 different views to the same Button variable.

Comment: I removed it - I've recreated the source code accordingly - but it still fails... (any insight is incredibly appreciated!)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HOoxxHSXNc9on015tFR3KmPOkUOX6jRSm3ic29DLFRA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: LOGCAT:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r5nusHvTkYrNR_X6z1-bHqCRQiIxHRxUN-nDa-anpnI/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you VERY much!! (I really appreciate it... I'm behind on a deadline and this is totally stumping me - and preventing me from getting it done!)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button button1,button2,button3;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    /*
     * Implementation for dynamic OnClicklisteners
     */
//      button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              openDialog(v);
//          }
//      });
//      button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              openDialog(v);
//          }
//      });
//      button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              openDialog(v);
//          }
//      });

}
public void openDialog(View v){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Settings Menu")
    .setMessage("Delete Edit or Link?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNeutralButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Edit",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    })
    .setPositiveButton("Link",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Link",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })    
    .setNegativeButton("Delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

            dialog.cancel();
        }
     });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    alertDialog.show();
}        





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:id="@+id/textView1"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Core Device 1" 
    android:onClick="openDialog" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Core Device 2" 
    android:onClick="openDialog" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button3" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Core Device 3" 
    android:onClick="openDialog" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can see the source at 
https://github.com/darussian/SimpleAndroidDialogExample

Comment: I REALLY appreciate your help with this! 

I implemented what you provided... however it still fails : (

SOURCE:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AJOl6Y-RcY_Z8lyKgS2panfCDrRVr5vLxZVdpGcY92Y/edit?usp=sharing


LOGCAT:


https://docs.google.com/document/d/12IXAUxlJ0vEWKE20iRTKGFSgZiOadFO6t7pUCG_Hp4w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You have a compilation error on SplashScreen.java. Also the OnClickListeners should be commented out. I was showing you two ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you very VERY much!! (I didn't implement the updated XML file as well) thank you!!!