# OnClick causes Force Close when attempting to open a Menu on 3 separate buttons

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been pointed in the correct direction by several people but I cannot seem to implement the source code suggested without continual force close issues. I know I'm overlooking something simple - I  truly appreciate any and all suggestions!

(all I really want to do is have the same menu appear for a 3 buttons when clicking them - I feel like I'm over thinking/coding this and there is a much simpler way to code this - or at least one like the way I've done below that actually works!)

---

### SOURCE

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bGpvLHii9G6uFgMMYxeSGGL9_5YiRBp3EgnHZjQgwD8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I Solved this question completely 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372732/button-onclick-listener-wont-call-alert-dialog/15372893#15372893

with source included

Comment: I'm still having trouble with it...